# How can I stop the js response from being executed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am using Rails3.1 + Jquery. I have two forms that submit "update" requests to the same controller. For one, I would like to display an alert to the users to tell them whether the request was successful. The other should be quiet. My controller code looks like this:

```
respond_to do |format|
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      format.html { redirect_to @user, :notice => 'Settings were successfully updated.' }
      format.json { head :ok }
      format.js { flash[:notice] = 'Settings were successfully updated.' }
...
```

The update.js is responsible for updating the flash div with the flash message. That works great. The problem is that this happens even from the form that I want to be silent. I'd like to modify the form itself to ignore any javascript in the response. I am having trouble finding anything in the Rails guides or through Google.

Answer (score 0):

You can also solve this using js, set a variable called caller which holds the value of the calling form, after getting ajax response check if caller is form1 show message else return;

pseudo code:

```
var caller;

//In ajax response
if (caller==1) {
//show message
} else {
return;
}
```